# Add custom 'Text' to a Custom Lookup Field (Use both)

Tags: formula, custom-field, picklist, lookup

I have recently converted a really long Picklist field that contained lots of Users to a custom lookup field (to make it neater and manageable e.g. not having to add users manually) however, the old Picklist field also had 'text options' as well as those manually inputted users names.

Is there a way to add those 'non user' text options to the list of users?

**UPDATE from questions:**

- As well as the referenced names the lookup should also contain 'text'
  words fields **'no preference'**, **'dept A user'**, **'dept B User'** if the
  user doesn't know which one to pick
- The lookup currently looks at the    USER object

Comment: You old picklist has multiple users but ur look up field will always point only to one user.what about the other users in the list and what exactly you want to add.As far as user is concerned,only users will be shown in the list.you can not show any non user in the list

Comment: @Samir I do want it to show the users --- sometimes the person may not know which user to choose so the picklist also contained 'no preference', 'dept A user', 'dept B User'.... I just want to add some 'text' to the list as well as the lookup's referenced users.

Comment: Your custom lookup points to USER object..Right?

Comment: @Samir Yes, the custom lookup points to USER

Comment: The lookup will only contains the list of user in SF.To add something like TEXT , you will need to create a user of that name.Or you can one custom object and populate it with the user name and add the text you want as well in that object.You look up will now point to this new object

Comment: So you are suggesting creating a new object add the username and my TEXT and use that to point to in my lookup? Is there any online guidance / tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: That is what i think. I am not sure if there is some better approach available or not.You can create a new object and run a soql in anonymour block to get the users and add them to the object

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Code to be run in Anonymous block

```
    list<User> lstUser = new list<User>();
    lstUser = [SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM User];
    //newObj__C is new custom object
    List<newObj__C> obj = new List<newObj__C>();
    for(user u : lstUser){
        String name = u.firstName + ' ' + u.LastName
        obj.add(new newObj(name = name);
    }

Database.insert (obj);
```

Please mark it as the answer if this answers your question

Comment: What is `newobj`?

Comment: it will be the new custom obj that has to be created